# FTP server Windows 8.1 error: 530 Login or password incorrect

Tags: ftp, windows-8.1, ftp-server

I follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-enEltDNko) steps by steps to create a local FTP Server on Windows 8.1. They use IIS to make FTP sites and add a Windows local user to login. But at the end, when I go to the server's IP address and login (using FireFox), I got this error: `530 Login or password incorrect!`. 

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

Select your FTP Site from IIS dashboard. than select FTP Authentications. Inside the FTP Authentications set the Basic Authentications Enabled.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too familiar with IIS but have used other FTP servers. Couple of things to check:

1. Are you logging in from the same machine / remote machine?
   If you are on the same machine, do you need the DOMAIN/Computer Name in there
2. Does the user you are trying to login as set up in IIS as being able to access the FTP Server?

Try checking the following,

1. User exists
2. User can access the FTP site
3. User you are entering into the FTP client has the right username and password.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. I got the error above because the FileZila is running in my system, stop it and there're no more problems.